# Orgmode : exporting agenda with sexps to ics

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda, sexp

This year, I am having classes with complex descriptions, such as "every 1st and 3rd friday between 2016-11-18 and 2017-5-19", so I chose to use org-mode agenda combined with sexps to describe them easily:

```
*17:00-19:00 Name of the class
 <%%(and
      (diary-block 11 18 2016 5 19 2017)
      (or
        (diary-float t 5 1)
        (diary-float t 5 3)
      ))>
```

Now, I want to export my schedule in the iCalendar format, to be able to use it in Lightning and/or Google Calendar. However, when I export it with `C-c C-e c f` (*ie* "Export current file to iCalendar"), I only get the events I input in classical timestamp format, *e.g.* `*Name of class <2016-12-12 Mon>`, although `org-icalendar-include-sexps` evaluates to `t`.

I also tried to use the agenda view exporting utility `C-c a e`, but encountered the same problem.

P.S. : I finally tried the alternative solution of directly importing my schedule to Google Calendar using org-gcal (https://github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el), to no avail.